# An Algorithm for Generating a random subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algorithms, permutations

I have given a group of permutations as a set of generators. I.e. $G=\langle g_1,...,g_k\rangle < S_n$. There are efficient algorithms (using stabilizer-chains and Schreier-Sims algorithm for example) for the following questions (and others)

1. determine the order of $G$
2. test whether a permutation $g\in S_n$ is in $G$ or not
3. generate a random element $g\in G$ (with nearly uniform distribution)

Now I would like to generate a random subgroup of $G$ (again given as a set of generators). The obvious way to do this is to just create a few random elements, but it seems this gives mostly trivial answers: When you select just two random elements from $S_n$, the probability of them generating $S_n$ or $A_n$ is approximately $1-1/n$ (Dixon's theorem). Similar results hold for other groups, i.e.: the chances of generating the whole $G$ with very few random elements are very high.

So the question:

1. Is there an algorithm to generate a subgroup of $G$ with more or less uniform distribution?
2. What about a random *maximal* subgroup? (so the algorithm could be iterated to get smaller groups)

Even the case $G=S_n$ would already be interesting to me.

Comment: I think if you really want arandom  subgroup with uniform distribution over all subgroups, then the only way to do it is to compute representatives of the conjugacy classes of all subgroups, or all maximal subgroups. For $G=S_n$, all subgroups are known up to $n=18$ and all maximal subgroups for $n$ up to a few thousand.